# Wordpress: Continues(loop) page navigation with get_permalink()

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, navigation

I would like to turn my page navigation in to a loop. I'm quit close but my problem is that I'm not able to switch between the categories. At the moment I have a loop inside of the category but I'm not able to jump to the next category.

As information: I have different post categories.

My script:

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true );
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false );
$prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;
$next_post_id = $next_post->ID;
?>
<?php
if(($prev_post_id === '') || ($prev_post_id === null)) :

$query = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'));

if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) :
$query->the_post();
$prev_post_id = get_the_ID();
endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;

if(($next_post_id === '') || ($next_post_id === null) ) :

$query = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'));

if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    $next_post_id = get_the_ID();
endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
?>


<div id="left">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev_post_id); ?>" class="myCursorPrev">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div id="right">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post_id); ?>" class="myCursorNext">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
$query = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'));
```

I tried different usage with the cat=4 or cat=1,2,3,4 but it has no effect.

Comment: Sry but I dont really understand what you want. Why turn your page navigation to a loop?

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. But doesn't <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?> and <?php next_posts_link('Next &raquo;') ?> outside the loop work for you?

Comment: yes this is working with out any problem. I'm getting closer but I'm still no able to do a loop through the categories. 
Take a look here: http://gaetan.alexandreessayie.com/wp/
click on the image for my navigation problem ...

Comment: Its working on the prev link it seems but not on the next link.